# How do I change the default file manager back to Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

A while back, I set my default file manager to Nemo. I like it a lot, but it constantly crashes. I remember editing a text file to set it as default, but I forgot which file it was. How do I switch back to the Nautilus file manager?

Comment: Official documentation for changing and restoring file manager: [Ubuntu documentation for Default File Manager ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)

Comment: Opposite of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This did it for me, after I google for a while:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

I also typed:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Comment: After that my Linux Mint failed to log in with X-session error `g_key_file_free: assertion 'key_file != NULL' failed`. To recover use Ctrl-Alt-F1 & `sudo apt-get cinnamon` and `sudo reboot`

Comment: The `xdg-mime` command worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.  I replaced `nautilus.desktop` with `pcmanfm.desktop` since I wanted to use that as my default file manager.  You can find the name of the file manager you want to use by using the following command `ls /usr/share/applications` and finding its corresponding `.desktop` file.

Comment: 5/5/20, it works on Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 22):

I spent AGES trying to find a method that would work. Eventually I found this advice, which is incredibly easy, and worked for me:

Install [`exo-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/exo-utils) (this package contains the Xfce settings plugin and the utility files for libexo-2-0). Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install exo-utils
```

Then run:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

then switch to Utilities tab and select File Manager you prefer.

*exo-preferred-applications* was dropped entirely in version 4.15.3-1. Install xfce4-settings with `sudo apt install xfce4-settings` and use this instead:

```
xfce4-mime-settings
```

Comment: It'll only work in Xubuntu or systems that have exo-utils installed

Comment: Is there any reason not to install exo-utils? (I use Ubuntu 16.04 and this method of changing the File Manager back to Nautilus, from Nemo, was the only method that worked, out of several I tried.)

Comment: Worked well for krusader after I installed it

Comment: This is the only way I could make `xdg-open` open directories with `nautilus` in Debian, thanks.

Comment: `xdg-open` seems to ignore this on 16.04.

Comment: Works fine for me. Just to mention that root and users have different settings so you need to run exo as user and/or as root respectivelly.

Comment: Worked great for me at Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS!

Comment: in Ubuntu 21.10 there is no `exo-preferred-applications` tool inside `exo-utils`

Answer (score 6):

The answers here didn't work for me on Debian Bookworm - so after figuring it out myself:

### Premise

Every time I attempt to leverage `xdg-open` on a directory (typically through an application; like Keybase's *"open in file explorer"* option, or something similar in Steam), what opens is Visual Studio Code.

### What doesnt work

Attempting to *"Open with other application"* a directory via the context menu in *"Files"* [Nautilus] (file explorer when using Gnome on Debian) and then *"Forget association"* on Visual Studio Code *(right click on it in the list of applications)*, subsequently choosing *"Files"* to open the directory with - does not fix what is used for directories when `xdg-open` is invoked; it only changes what opens a directory from within *"Files"* [Nautilus].

### What does work

Run the following:

```bash
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

The standard, as explained, is as follows:

1. `xdg-mime default`

   - We're setting a default application
2. `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

   - We're setting the default application to be Nautilus, by its fully-qualified desktop menu name; It's registered as `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`.
3. `inode/directory`

   - For the mimetype `inode/directory` *(found using `xdg-mime query filetype /path/to/target`, with target in my case being a directory.)*

The accepted answer results in `Nautilus.desktop` and `application/x-gnome-saved-search` becoming the default application(s); which is not correct, it must needs be `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`.

Also, setting desktop icons to be shown won't set the default application when opening directories via `xdg-open`.

Alternatively, you can also set it as follows:

```bash
nano ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Scroll down to `inode/directory` under `[Added Associations]`, as well under `[Default Applications]`, and ensure that the line(s) read:

```bash
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

You can additionally add, under `[Removed Associations]`:

```bash
inode/directory=code.desktop;
```

This is just the manual, longer, way of doing what I suggested first - together with the *"Forget association"* bit I portrayed I had attempted

### Restore Behavior in Terminal

A user provided edit surmises that one should source the default list of file associations "for immediate effect". This answer, however, focuses on file associations for when xdg-open is invoked by another application.

With that in mind, and in reviewing the default file associations (on Debian and Ubuntu) at `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`;

The default file does not seem to provide the aforementioned association. However, in the event that it did, and/or in the event that you wanted an immediate reflection of the default file associations in terminal (i.e. you're `xdg-open`'ing something in terminal) - you could source the default list in your current terminal session:

```bash
source /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Comment: This has got to be the oldest thread I’ve seen revived, 7 years later

Comment: @nick It's a good question because it can stump people who've used Debian/Ubuntu for even longer; and 7 years later the answer(s) can/will change. You should never hesitate to answer a question regardless of its age; especially if the question exists already - and the historic answer doesn't work any longer. People are encouraged *not* to repeat questions; stack has evolved its products so that answers may stack according to most recent upvotes (recent preference changes, you may have noticed). In a sense revival isn't really a thing, because ongoing support is supported/expected.

Answer (score 3):

The file manager choice is handled by a file in `~/.local/share/applications`. They are `mimeapps.list` and `mimeinfo.cache`, deleting both of those files will reset your file manager to the default, which is Nautilus.

Comment: I'm afraid that solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo mv /usr/bin/nemo /usr/bin/nemo.backup`
2. Open any folder. You could use `xdg-open /path/to/folder/` while in the command line, for example. Or you could use a X application that requests a file.
3. A dialog should appear to you requesting a default application to be your file manager. Type `/usr/bin/nautilus` there and confirm.

After that, as long as you don't rename *nemo* to its original name/location, nautilus will be your default file manager again.