# Make nemo the default file browser

Tags: filemanager, nemo

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, then installed Nemo. Now I would like to make Nemo the default file manager.  I've searched the web for a solution but every time I restart my computer Nautilus come back.

Does anyone know an effective solution?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a much better way to do this without moving files and setting links. Just open a terminal with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and perform this command:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Then set up Nemo to handle your desktop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Revert this changes:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Comment: I found that this method doesn't set nemo as the default file manager when, for example, opening an external hard drive from the launcher. I used the other answer and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @duxk.gh I do not use Unity, so can't test that.

Comment: In my case with 12.04 LTS the other answer worked well, this one was still launching nautilus as file manager

Comment: How would this work for Dolphin? Tried with [this one] but didnt work for me on a 16.04

Answer (score 24):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then paste this:

```
 sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/nautilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nemo /usr/bin/nautilus
```

then try again, hope that helps.

Note that this will effectively make Nautilus inaccessible on your system unless you modify shortcuts to point to `nautilus.back`.

Comment: this is a hack, yet very effective! :)

Comment: @Raja, This is a great answer.  It's the only one that I find that will work.  Hopefully eventually setting your default file browser will become a workable feature as with setting the default web browser.   With this resolution, if you have an occasion to want to call Nautilus you can call it with nautilus.back.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you possibly put a command to reverse these changes for the sake of completion? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea.  But this doesn't seem to work in debian cinnamon.  It runs nautilus ok from the terminal, but not from within cinnamon via Accessories | Files, nor via Package Manager | Extract | show files, and probably elsewhere too.  Just does nothing in these two cases.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 at the moment

Comment: this works, for Xubuntu 18 to replace thunar adjust the command replace `/nautilus` with `/thunar` because XFCE uses `thunar`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on 18.04 (source [here](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/tweaking-ubuntu/change-default-filemanager)):

If you have Nemo installed on your system and want to set Nemo as the default file manager, run this command in a terminal:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

To revert this, enter

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Nemo (the `nemo.desktop` app launcher to be exact) should now be the default file manager. To test the result, run this command:

```
xdg-open $HOME
```

That command should launch Nemo showing your home directory.