# Turn off Auto Search in Nautilus 3.8

Tags: nautilus

Does anyone know how to turn off the auto search in nautilus 3.8. In previous versions when I pressed a key it would select the first item that started with that letter/key in directory I was in. Now if I do this is automatically preforms a search as filters all items which is really annoying (and slow). Does anyone know how to turn this off and revert to the old behavior. I checked preferences but there's nothing there.

Comment: Nautilus 3.8? How did you install that? The current version in Quantal is 3.4!

Comment: I'm currently using 13.04 beta. Also please do not give me BS about 13.04 not being supported at this time and closing this question. 13.04 is being released next week and the problem I'm having is not a bug, it is a "feature" of Nautilus 3.8.

Comment: I am not giving you any "BS" (whatever that is) - I was just asking a question.

Comment: this question has been asked and answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking (and many other nice features) is not possible in nautilus 3.6/3.8. [This tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-nautilus-34-features-back-in-ubuntu.html) explains how to install a pached nautilus 3.4 in ubuntu 13.04