# how do I disable recursive search in nautilus 3.6

Tags: nautilus, search

Recursive search in nautilus 3.6 completely breaks my keyboard navigation. I often navigate network volumes, and typing to get directly to a folder and clicking enter was very quick. Now typing removes everything in the view and imposes a 30 second delay which is completely useless.

If it showed whats in the current directory immediately, and then searched it would be fine, but as it is now I just want to turn it off. I couldn't find anything in dconf-settings. Anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traditional search-as-you-type on newer Nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment it doesn't seem like you can revert back to the nautilus 3.4 behaviour. There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1164016).

In the meantime you can install `nemo`, a fork of nautilus 3.4, that integrates seamlessly with the Ubuntu desktop. To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

Comment: Thanks, that's immediately more comfortable than nautilus :)

Comment: Unfortunately many applications, like Dropbox, are integrated with Files (Nautilus), so if you use another file explorer you will lose some features.