# Mark first file in filemanager starting on letter "x" (mimicking windows)

Tags: 13.04, files, filemanager, interface

In windows, when I am looking for a file in the current directory which name I (at-least partly) know. I simply start by pressing the first letter in the name, to jump to the first item starting with that letter.

In the default Ubuntu file-manager, it instead starts a search showing all items containing whatever input. How can I mimic the windows way?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285793/how-do-i-disable-recursive-search-in-nautilus-3-6) and the bug report: [#1164016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1164016).

Comment: Thanks!! Might aswell mark my question as duplicate. Something i think is wierd tough is how everyone sees this ubuntos fault not using the older version rather than nautilus fault not supporting type-ahead find. The reports should be sent to the team behind nautilus rather than ubunto.

Comment: The bug is actually in the `nautilus` page of Launchpad, so it's being sent to the team responsible for Nautilus, I guess. :)