# How can I downgrade to an older version of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

It looks like that nautilus have changed a lot since previous version, I hate the way it is on ubuntu 13.04 (Installed it yesterday)

First of all, a lot of features are gone, next, if I start typing sth, it will search for it which is soooo bad! is there anyway to go back to previous version? (of course I was unable to fine a way.

EDIT: looks like nemo file manager is a fork of nautilus 3.4 by linuxmint dev. they were not satisfied with nautilus 3.6 (like me) I guess that will do it ;)

Comment: It may be time to look for alternatives.

Comment: Alternative file manager of distribution? :D I liked nautilus! this is a disaster for me :(

Comment: This might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Grab Nemo (Linux Mint team forked nautilus 3.4, because they don't like what was changed in 3.6)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Comment: good choice because you don't have to install any patched version, but more secure a separate software

Comment: I prefer this approach because I can run "_Files_" 3.6.3 from Raring alongside of _Nemo_ 1.1.2.

btw I only installed nemo, nemo-fileroller was automatically installed. 

XRef: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-nemo-file-manager-in.html

Comment: works great.  thankyou for 'finding nemo'

Comment: BE CAREFUL. This made me unable to log in to my Unity session from then onwards, I had to purge the packages to get back in. The PPA for Cinnamon doesn't guarantee stability alongside Unity.

Answer (score 5):

On 13.04 you can fairly easily downgrade to a patched version of the older Nautilus 3.4 by adding a PPA managed by the good people at [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/).

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/experiments
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
killall nautilus
```

For a full description of the patched version (and how to remove it), see this article:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-nautilus-34-features-back-in-ubuntu.html

N.B.: If the `dist-upgrade` command attempts to remove packages, there is a problem and you should **not** continue. Otherwise things should be fine.

Comment: This is a lifesaver! Thank you so much. This fixes all the issues I have been having. 1) typing resulted in a recursive search. 2) Issues with nautilus not showing up above other windows when launched from CLI 3)Generally a worse look. This also still works with RabbitVCS no breakages.

Comment: This did nothing for me. I'm on Ubuntu Gnome, might that be why?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu Gnome, so I'm not sure. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can downgrade to the Nautilus version that came with Quantal (12.10).

Here you find the instruction how to do that:

- In the Dash, type 'Software & Updates'. (Don't type the single quotes.)
- Start the 'Software & Updates' program.
- Choose the tab 'Other Software'.
- Add a new software repository. If you want the Quantal repository, type

  `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main`
- and save.
- Open Synaptic Package Manager.

  If Synaptic Package Manager is not installed, you should type 'Ubuntu Software Center' in the dash. There you choose to install 'Synaptic Package Manager'.
- Choose 'Reload' to update the package information.
- In the Quick search field, type: nautilus, and select nautilus in the list.
- In the menu choose: Package - Force version.
- Choose the Quantal version.
- In the menu choose: Package - Lock Version.
- Log out, log in.