# Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04 opens underneath other windows

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

This applies to Ubuntu 13.04 and not 12.04.

Whenever I launch Nautilus from the terminal by typing `nautilus` it is opened up beneath my other currently active windows. However this does not happen if I launch 'files' from the Launcher in the top left, which begs the question, what command is that running?

Is there a way to resolve this so that Nautilus will always open on top of everything else when launched by a terminal command?

[Here is a video demonstrating the issue.](http://youtu.be/T_OdJl4rZ0s)

---

**Update**

It turns out that if you `killall nautilus` and then perform `nautilus --new-window --no-desktop &` Nautilus will now pop up at the very top as expected. However now I cannot see any desktop icons and 'expo' shows every window as active.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do was to perform these steps to 'downgrade' to an older patched version of nautilus. This seems to have fixed all my problems without generating any new ones.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/experiments
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
killall nautilus
```

This is based on an answer provided to another [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286056/how-can-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-of-nautilus).