# Free typing in Nautilus: how to make it select elements instead of running a search?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

When using Nautilus, sometimes I want to jump do a directory (or a file) that I *know* is in there, but I don't want to *visually* look for it.  The easy way to do that in Windows (and, for what I can remember, in previous versions of Ubuntu) is to simply type the element's name and the window manager will browse the displayed element in order to find it.  Right after that, you just have to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to open it.

For instance, if I'm in my `home` folder and want to access the `dev` folder, I just type `de`, <kbd>enter</kbd> and I'm in it.

[image: home folder in which I want to reach a specific item]

Instead of that, in Ubuntu 13.04, when you free type while you're in Nautilus, it will run a search (I don't know in which scope: the whole folder you're in, I suppose).

[image: search in the home folder]

Is it possible to disable this mechanism and restore the previous one ?

Comment: Note that I'm not 100% sure it's a Nautilus related issue; it might be related to Unity.  Do not hesitate to edit if you have more information about it, thanks !

Comment: Hell, this is a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/275883/42196