# Nautilus - Disabling the '/' shortcut

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

Since I have fallen in love in nautilus terminal and nautilus itself I found it really frustrating when it comes to type the path to some directories etc. on nautilus window.

Every time I tap '/' or '~' it opens the dialog to write the path there. I want to disable that behavior. Is there an extension or some tool to achieve it?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you screenshot what you mean for clarity?

Comment: What else do you want it to do? Pressing / or ~ starts the folder search and pressing any other letter searches the current folder for files. As this is integrated in Nautilus, it is highly unlikely you can change this without adjusting the source and recompiling.

Comment: I would like it doesn't start search

Comment: IDK if this will help but it will revert nautilus to its traditional search feature http://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions might disable the folder search.