# Enable recursive search in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 16.10, ubuntu-gnome

After I upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, typing in Nautilus no longer searches through the folder structure recursively, but rather just skips to a file in the folder (the old "type-ahead" mechanism).

Why is this? Is the Ubuntu version of Nautilus patched to do this? How can I enable the standard Nautilus search behavior?

NOTE: This question is the opposite of [Traditional search-as-you-type on newer Nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions) -- I'm trying to enable global search, disable local search.

Answer (score 3):

I feel the same way about recursive search so here is a fix for newer versions of Ubuntu:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search false
```

Nautilus should immediately show a change in behavior.

Please let me know if this doesn't work for you, thanks!

Comment: After upgrading to a new version, global search was re-enabled, so now I can't test it out.
Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu 17.04 for me

Comment: @RobAu I don't know. It works for me on 17.04 using nautilus on unity7. Maybe you want the other behavior? Did you try setting this to true instead of false?

Answer (score 2):

Open a Nautilus window, then go to Preferences.  Go to Search & Preview tab and make sure "search in subfolders" is set to local computer, or all locations, as you need.

Comment: It is set to "search in subfolders". Doesn't effect anything.