# How do I disable search-as-you-type text in Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Tags: nautilus, search

I cannot find enable-interactive-search in

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search true.
```

I searched using

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep search
```

and

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep interactive
```

but no such option.

Can you help me disable this in Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu does no longer provide this feature from 17.10 onwards.
Source: http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-17-10-to-ship-with-nautilus-3-24-file-manager-without-type-ahead-search-513211.shtml

Comment: This is frustrating and needlessly stupid.

Comment: Install [Nemo](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3)

Answer (score 56):

Gnome decided to [remove](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2012-August/msg00002.html) the navigation feature *type-ahead* and replace it with search. They fail to see this is a big problem for many users.

Up until Ubuntu 17.10 Canonical provided a patched version of Nautilus that retained this feature. This is not the case anymore and type-ahead is gone for good.

You are of course welcome to join the [Nautilus mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/nautilus-list) and state your reasons why this feature is still needed. I don't see much use in that, though. One of the maintainers told me *"This has been discussed to death and we have likely heard all the arguments."*

Comment: This is quite frustrating, as I (and apparently others too) use that feature frequently. For what it's worth, disabling recursive search brings behavior a bit closer to the old type-ahead one (but also affects the explicit Ctrl-F search, as those are the same): `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences recursive-search 'never'`

Comment: As someone who uses the file browser with my keyboard a lot, their decision is just a deal-breaker for me. I simply cannot keep using Nautilus if this isn't fixed. I noticed there's a bug on Launchpad regarding this, already. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1164016

Comment: Here's a more recent bug, discussing the issue. Please voice your opinion:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1666681

Comment: Another one, closed but still active as of april 2018: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/244

Comment: TontonManu answer on the ppa shws a great solution to this. It would be interesting to see how much this ppa is used, which could be a clear argument that many users consider it a big problem! And thanks @gromit190 for the links, I went there and upvoted/thumbed up every complaint on that issue!

Comment: On local SSDs, this is no big deal. However, Search causes nautilus to crash and hang autofs when browsing NFS mounts on both Ubuntu and Arch linux clients. I suspect this has something to do with the maximum number of requests allowed to the NFS server, which cannot change in my situation. Thanks for providing the background info on this issue, @mniess.

Comment: @JamesHemsing Even with an SSD, this feature can make Nautilus unusable, as it still can have a significant delay as it searches all files, sometimes finding a ton of garbage results that have a partial match for every key press. I have an SSD, and this is quite possibly the biggest usability regression in the current release. I really wish the Gnome team would stop snatching defeat from the jaws of victory.

Answer (score 35):

Woohoooo! There is a brand new modified version of Nautilus.

See https://launchpad.net/~lubomir-brindza/+archive/ubuntu/nautilus-typeahead

I've been waiting for a long time before I find this feature again. Hope that Nautilus developers will consider adding it as an option in the app.

Comment: Best answer, this seems to work great

Comment: Ok, I 've added the PPA, but how can I install it?

Comment: Thanks man. This was what I have bee looking for.

Answer (score 21):

I've participated to long debates with the Nautilus developers and we were not able to be convincing enough to have this feature as it was before. The only response was that it was going to be improved in the future.

I like Nautilus but this change made it unusable for me. That drives me crazy.

My solution is simple: switch to another software. I now use Nemo which is fork of Nautilus.

Comment: How do you switch the file manager to Nemo?

Comment: @birgersp what do you mean? just install nemo `sudo apt install nemo` and use it  ... if you fail to find it after install - open terminal, type `nemo` and hit enter (**without s̶u̶d̶o̶**)

Comment: @birgersp then just add it to favorites or panel - it's just a program there is no "file manager switching" unless you'd have it in "Default Applications" - then you'd switch it there...

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to have this functionality in Nautilus 3.26 (which is right now the current version in Ubuntu 17.10), check out my step-by-step guide to get it in this question: [Traditional search-as-you-type on newer Nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions/1002518#1002518) to build your own version of Nautilus with the support patched back in!

> There is actually a way to get this in Nautilus 3.26 (the current
>   version in Ubuntu 17.10), which is building your own version from
>   source using a patch provided by the awesome Arch Linux community.
>   Luckily the great build system in Ubuntu makes this quite easy.
>   Here are the steps. I'll assume you'll be working in
>   `~/bld-nautilus-typeahead`. Open the terminal and do the following:
>
> ```
> # install some necessary tools
> sudo apt-get install git
>
> # Create your work directory and go there
> mkdir bld-nautilus-typeahead ; cd bld-nautilus-typeahead
>
> # Clone the repository holding the needed patch: 
> git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/nautilus-typeahead.git
>
> # Make sure the source repositories for the main archives are available:
> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> # If the deb-src line for the main repository (usually around line 6)   
> # is commented out (starts with a #)     
> # uncomment it (remove the #) and save the file.  
> sudo apt-get update
>
> # Install the build dependencies
> sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
>
> # Retrieve the sources for Nautilus
> apt-get source nautilus
>
> # Source should now be in the 'nautilus-3.26.0/' folder. Go there
> cd nautilus-3.26.0/
>
> # and Apply the patch from arch-linux
> patch -p0 < ../nautilus-typeahead/nautilus-restore-typeahead.patch
>
> # Build the package from source
> dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
>
> # This will take a little time. If everything goes well, the related packages will end up in the parent directory. Go there
> cd ..
>
> # and install the required packages
> sudo dpkg -i nautilus_3.26.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb nautilus-data_3.26.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
> ```
>
> Start a new Nautilus. Type some letters. Experience that feeling of
>   joy that happens when the file you intended gets selected.