# How can I make selecting files/folders in the file browser by typing a name act smoother?

Tags: nautilus

I have a habit of using the keyboard to navigate through my files and folders. I start typing the name of the file/folder I want to select in the file browser, and then hit ENTER to open it.

With Ubuntu 17.10, the file browser goes a little crazy when I start typing. It triggers some kind of searching feature, and lists all the files or folders that it finds (recursively) matching the text that I've typed. This annoys me quite a lot, I just wanted the folder in the current directory with a matching name to be selected.

Example:

I want to enter the folder "Anaconda3" from here.

[image: file browser]

So I start typing "anaco" and as I type, search results are changing quite frantically as the search criteria changes.

[image: search results]

This is not what I want the file browser to do. I just want to select the "Anaconda3" folder, like so:

[image: folder selected]

Is there any way to make the file browser act the way I want? Or should I just create a feature request at Ubuntu for it?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable search as you type text in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967022/how-to-disable-search-as-you-type-text-in-ubuntu-17-10) and [Nautilus doesn't have type-ahead search in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967242/nautilus-doesnt-have-type-ahead-search-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, you can't – with default Nautilus file manager.

Ubuntu 17.10 ships with Nautilus 3.24 file manager that no longer has the 'type-ahead search' feature available (not even as an option in the preferences).
This has been [discussed a lot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967022/how-to-disable-search-as-you-type-text-in-ubuntu-17-10/968016#968016) but it looks like developers will stick to their decision to keep this feature replaced by the search.

Alternatives:

- Open Nautilus Preferences > Search & Preview > set 'Serch in subfolders' to 'never' and uncheck 'Full Text Search: set as default'. This way you will only get files and folders within the current folder if you start typing.
- Press `ctrl + l` in file manager to open location input and type a folder name to open there that will be auto-completed.
- Install a different file manager. For example [Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294421/how-do-i-install-nemo-file-manager) is a fork of nautlius that preserves some features like the [type ahead find](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo).

Comment: Thanks! I Installed Nemo, and it works like a charm. Hopefully the Nautilus developers will realize that 'type-ahead search' is (arguably) a must-have!