# Why does Nautilus' search function jam directory navigation?

Tags: nautilus, search

In Ubuntu 18.04, I do this:

- Super-E to open Nautilus
- Click on `Home`
- Type a letter of a desired directory, e.g. `d` if I want to go to `Documents`.
- I then try to mouse-click on `Documents`. But at this point, Nautilus is jammed for three minutes until eventually I get a popup notification that "Search for d is ready."

My user home has only 52 directories and 22 other files.

I think that the entire subtree of my user-home is being searched for that letter `d`. How do I avoid that? I do wish I could use that `d` keypress to go to the right part of the directory listing.

Comment: I guess this is not possible anymore https://askubuntu.com/questions/967022/how-do-i-disable-search-as-you-type-text-in-ubuntu-17-10-and-later

Comment: So you hit the first letter in the directory name, Nautilus finds it, but won't let you exit the search ? Try hitting Esc once Nautilus shows the directory, see if it let's you press Enter afterwards

Comment: I tried that. It does not make a difference.  I do this.
(1) Type Superkey+E  (to open Nautilus) (2) Click Home (3) Type d (4) Esc (5) Mouse-click on Documents, or else Type Enter (though actually, the first 'd' directory is not Documents).

Anyway, Nautilus is frozen at stage 3

Comment: Thank you. That link led me to this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1164016

Comment: Unfortuantely, adding the repo as recommended there, I get "gpg: unknown option 'show-only' ; gpg: invalid import options ; Got '0' fingerprints, expected only one ; Failed to add key.