# Make typing in the file explorer just scroll down to that file alphabetically rather than search

Tags: files, search

In previous versions of Ubuntu typing in the file explorer would scroll down your directory alphabetically based on your typing. Now it does a find/search which is much slower and... a horrible experience for my frankly.

Is there a way to change this behaviour back to how it used to be?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible as I know... that feature has been dropped in nautilus. You can use other file managers instead, things like nemo, thunar, etc.

Comment: @Marogian nice catch! FYI Caja from MATE DE has this functionality in all supported Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @Marogian I have just tested patched Nautilus from `ppa:lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead` on my 18.04.1 LTS. It works as before. Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/278553/66509).