# Which desktop environment will let me jump to the next file with the same first letter in filename, when I press a key few times with delay

Tags: gnome, nautilus, search

I am pretty annoyed with this on Gnome that when you hit a key few times you end up typing a word in the search bar instead of jumping to the next search result.

Are there some other DE that do it like Windows? It is far more convenient way to find something quick imo. Why this is impossible on Ubuntu?

Here is the demonstration in total commander

[image]

> [image]

Comment: @N0rbert I have added a demonstration. Non of the answers actually work

Comment: @mevsme In that case, can you specify the expected behaviour again? I don't see how your demonstration differs from the konqueror behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a few file managers in a VM and Konqueror seems to meet your needs in that particular instance. Install with `sudo apt install konqueror`.
You might want to switch to e.g. Kubuntu for good though, because it needs all the KDE dependencies, and it looks out of place in GNOME, but since you were asking for a desktop environment anyway that might not be a problem for you.

I found this relevant piece of information [in the docs](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konqueror/konqueror/selection.html#selection-keyboard)

> Select a file or folder by typing the first few letters of its name
> and the first matching item is selected. To clear the selection and
> cancel the keyboard search press Esc **or wait longer than the timeout
> of 1 second.**

(emphasis mine)

I did find, however, that you don't need to wait if it's unambiguous.

[image: A (not so) fancy gif to show how it's working]

Comment: Another is Dolphin.

Comment: I haven't tried this one, but you can add it as an answer. Maybe it's even a better solution if it doesn't need the heavy KDE libs?

Comment: I have not used my Ubuntu for a few weeks. Let me double check before posting an answer. I think Dolphin needs heavy KDE libs too. In general, KDE is so friendly and configurable compared to recent versions of GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Caja file-manager (from `caja` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/caja)) provides this functionality - see screencast below:

[image: Caja]

Note: <kbd>Esc</kbd> is really not needed, you can wait for timeout to be reached.

Also you maybe interest in removing GNOMEs Hell and installing whole traditional and cool MATE Desktop environment instead. See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233025/66509) for details.

Comment: How did you record your screen and key-presses? OBS?

Comment: I see on screen-cast that the user are pressing down and escape - that's the default behavior actually. The behavior that I want is: you press **b** few times with delay, and selection goes like `bin` > `boot` > `bin`  
  
The point is that I don't want to move my hand to arrows and Esc key

Comment: I press Esc to enter other letter. Please look more carefully.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it's not really a suitable answer.

Comment: I searched for `b`. Then I want to search for `d`, `e`, `h`. To close search field I use Esc. @Fynn you can always record better GIF. The [main issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/275883/66509) is fixed.

Comment: The question implicitly states that he wants the following functionality "when you hit a key few times you [...] jump to the next search result". This is not what caja is doing, or am I wrong?

Comment: @N0rbert sry, forgot the ping

Comment: Oh I see ... yes, that ‘nautilus-typeahead‘ package seems to be a suitable answer

Comment: @Fynn The recorded behavior in my answer is equal to old Nautilus 3.4.2. Really it is hard to find the version or application which reacts on multiple single letter press. Maybe twin-panes like Krusader or DoubleCommander will do the job, but both of them are not preinstalled.