# Why doesn't Ubuntu make it's own File manager

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I don't like the current nautilus, and I think the upcoming versions are just going to make it worse, so why doesn't Ubuntu make it's own file manager? Just like Mint did with Nemo), or at least fork Nemo, I don't think I'm the only one who has this idea.

Comment: This is a question and answer forum about the operative system, but your question is more a "wish-list" kind of debate. Anyway, you may be interested in reading [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-create-new-file-manager-unity). And I agree, nautilus in it's current state is useless for many of us.

Comment: [Ubuntu To Create New File Manager for Unity 8 Desktop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-create-new-file-manager-unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/nemo/) - it was created as part of the Cinnamon desktop, on Linux Mint, due to similar loathing to Nautilus - though it is based Nautilus 3.4, and still has the dual pane feature, and other things, that Nautilus had a while back.

[ [image: Nemo]

There is an article [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) on WebUPD8 that may of help - It offers a patched version that does not require Cinnamon to be installed, and with Unity integration. It uses [this](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/nemo) PPA.

There is a helpful question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-as-default-file-browser) on making Nemo the default File Manager.

Wiki page on Nemo [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_%28file_manager%29) - other file managers are listed at the bottom.

If this is not what you want, see @blade19899 's above comment.