# Disk space Indicator for Files (Nautilus) application in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus

Is there any method to add a disk space indicator to *Files* in 18.04? Something as in Windows 10 or Cinnamon would be great.

Comment: If you think like me, that Files (=`nautilus`) lacks features, you can [use `nemo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser) (the default for Linux Mint).

Comment: I upvoted it. Thanks. But it was detached from the file manager and has no drive name. It is easy to access version of disk analyzer app.  I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Install GNOME extension "Disk Space Usage" found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1447/disk-space-usage/).

Other GNOME extensions can be found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org).