# How can I see hidden folders in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

Can someone please tell me how I can display hidden folders with Nautilus?

Comment: Linux means freedom. Install your preferred file manager and be happy. I like [Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser).

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+H show them?

Answer (score 1):

Click the menu button the left of minimize button and tick **Show Hidden Files** checkbox:

[image]