# Windows like searching for files

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, filemanager, search

When you use the explorer in Windows and start typing some letters, the explorer automatically focuses files that starts with the same letters you typed. When I try to do this in Ubuntu's file manager (Nautilus), it starts searching overall for files instead of focusing them directly.

How can I change this to behave like Windows' explorer?

Comment: [Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser) will do ...

Comment: Desktop Search (instead of File Manager) seems to do wha tyou want, too.