# Revert to Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, filemanager

After I installed Cinnamon, Nemo automatically installed itself, and now Nemo is default file browser. How can I revert to Nautilus.

Comment: Similar or  the same question - these questions probably need to be merged when we get an accepted solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235660/how-do-i-change-the-default-file-manager-back-to-nautilus/244181#244181

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this.

1. Try running `exo-preferred-applications` from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> ). You should see an option to change your file manager on the 2nd tab named "Utilities".

   [image]
2. Using `xdg-mime`, You could also run the following command to determine your current default file manager:

   - `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`
   - This should return `nemo.desktop` as a result.
   - In order to change this, run:
   - `xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application`
3. You can edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

   - look for the line containing `inode/directory=nemo.desktop;`
   - change it to read `inode/directory=nautilus.desktop;`

Comment: when I run xdg-mime query default inode/directory i get nautilus.desktop as result. But when I double click on folder it's opened in Nemo.

Comment: I tried exo-preferred-applications before, but no effect, also I tried your third solution, again, no effect

Comment: @Alen [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=112854) is a link that mentions a few options for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried them all and still not working. When i right click on folder I have Nautilus as secondary option, is there a way to set it as primary. And for the record, I just removed Nemo and it's still appearing :O