# How to change the file manager for Rubbish bin back to Nautilus?

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, trash

After I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 whenever I open the rubbish bin it opens with PCManFM. Nautilus opens as the file manager for everything else. 
EDIT: PCManFM only is used when I open the rubbish bin from the launcher.

[image]

How do I get the rubbish bin to open with Nautilus?

Comment: Cool GTK and icon theme! What are they?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  GTK theme is [Royal](https://medium.com/@foxoman/royal-ubuntu-theme-40a635534e1) and icon theme is [uniform+](http://0rax0.deviantart.com/art/Uniform-Icon-Theme-453054609)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/288136/124777) to reset back to nautilus

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```