# Can't open desktop folders in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, file-association

I have a quite fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, When I create a directory on Desktop, I can't open it by double clicking on it. I have to right click → *Open with other application* → *Files* and then it works (it also works when I open Files manager and then go to "Desktop" and select that directory). How do I fix this?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using ? gnome ?

Comment: What's the first entry in the context menu above "Open with other applications" or is that the first entry?

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser yes, I'm using GNOME

Comment: @DavidFoerster this is what is shown to me when I select "Open with other applications": https://i.imgur.com/wyeJSiD.png

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer my question. Also, could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Woops, sorry I misread it, my previous comment is a nonsense in this context. The first option above "Open with other applications" is "Open in new window"

Comment: What happens when you select "Open in new window"? Can you open other desktop entries (e. g. image files or application launchers) with a double-click? If you have no other desktop entries, could you please create one or more to try?

Comment: Nothing happens. This also applies to "Open in new tab"

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160007/103266) by @Aashutosh Taikar worked for me in ubuntu 18.10:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.mate.freedesktop.FileManager1.service
```

After restarting my PC I was once more able to open desktop folders and the Rubbish Bin by double-clicking on their icons.

Before doing this nothing would happen when I clicked on them, and I'd just see error messages like this in my `/var/log/syslog`:

```
nautilus-deskto[1854]: cannot open folder on desktop, freedesktop bus not ready
```