# Not able to open Files in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, files, taskbar

This happens most of the time when i click on `Files` which is located at `Task Bar` it din't opens i `Google` about this i found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063813/not-able-to-open-desktop-icons-folders-but-able-to-open-files) which is not worked for me or maybe i typed wrong id please help me.

Comment: Can you open folders from the terminal as `nautilus ~/Documents`

Comment: Hello @giray thanks for your reply but i've got solution i'll post it as a solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution from some article and it worked for me just type this command

```
$ killall nautilus
```

this will kill all nautilus running processes