# Gnome desktop on 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

[image]

After install ubuntu 18.04 i cant open and run icons on desktop. i try install nautilus and other extensions but this problem is stay . please help to fix it

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has Gnome already and Nautilus is installed by default. Also your desktop shows no icons for running apps.

Comment: home, trash, mounted dist in desktop ...

Comment: The screenshot shows a correctly functioning desktop. Can we have more details?

Comment: You mean this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/984153/cant-open-desktop-folders-by-double-clicking-on-ubuntu-17-10?

Comment: Emm , when OS is boot. after click on any icon on desktop i have not any act , but after open 'File Manager' and close it , i can open , run applications with cllick on desktop icon. it need before run a time run 'file manager'